# How to know what is causing my action to run into multiple threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have a simple form submission with almost 5 fields and on submission it runs into 4 threads and hence save 4 entries in table on a single post method call.
I have attached an image and code for relevancy of the issue i am facing.

My controller :

```
public ActionResult Test(CustomerOrderVM CustomerOrderVM)
{
    try
    {
        if (CustomerOrderVM.Email == "")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please enter valid Country");
        }

        if (CustomerOrderVM.City == "" || CustomerOrderVM.City == "< Select City >")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("City", "Please enter valid City");
        }

        if (CustomerOrderVM.Contact == "")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Contact", "Please enter valid Contact Number");
        }

        if (CustomerOrderVM.FullName == "")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("FullName", "Please enter valid FullName");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            tblCustomerOrder _tblCustomerOrder = new tblCustomerOrder();

            _tblCustomerOrder.FullName = CustomerOrderVM.FullName;
            _tblCustomerOrder.Address = CustomerOrderVM.Address;
            _tblCustomerOrder.City = CustomerOrderVM.City;
            _tblCustomerOrder.Contact = CustomerOrderVM.Contact;
            _tblCustomerOrder.Email = CustomerOrderVM.Email;
            _tblCustomerOrder.Proceeded = false;

            db.tblCustomerOrders.Add(_tblCustomerOrder);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(CustomerOrderVM);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Error";
        return Json(ViewBag.Error);
    }
}
```

My ViewModel :

```
public class CustomerOrderVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid name")]
    [Display(Name = " Name")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid name", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Email Id", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid  Mobile No")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Mobile No", MinimumLength = 9)]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile No")]
    public string Contact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Street Address")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid address", MinimumLength = 7)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Proceeded")]
    public bool? Proceeded { get; set; }
}
```

My View :

```
@model applicaton.Models.ViewModels.CustomerOrderVM

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>



 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure",
        LoadingElementId = "progress"
    }))
    {

        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="fent">
        <input type="hidden" name="affiliate" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="index">
        <input type="hidden" name="short_referrer" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="long_referrer" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="free" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="avial" id="avial" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="pack" id="pack" value="">


 <div class="form-box">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control MaxWidth uppercase", @placeholder = "Name" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>



     <div class="form-box">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control MaxWidth uppercase", @placeholder = "Email" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>


     <div class="form-box">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Contact : 923xxxxxxxxx", @maxlength = "12" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-box">
               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control MaxWidth uppercase auto-text-area", @placeholder = "Street Address" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-box">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(new string[] {"< Select City >",//Cities}, "< Select City >"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })



  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button redcolor large `enter code here`submit-form">Place My Order!</button>

}
```

This is an issue, there are 4 threads running pointed by yellow highlighter **ATTACHED BELOW**

POST Method Calls Generating from browser 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFWrK.png)

Comment: How do you know there’s threads and does that matter? Did you debug to see what’s happening and that you’re not sending several requests?

Comment: Add please your client code, that might trigger several post requests

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Like i mentioned in the question on one post action its saving 4 entries in my sql table so i checked threads running on that method and i found 4 threads.

Comment: How did you check them? And did you check what requests came through? What is making the requests? I don’t think amount of threads has anything to do with this.

Comment: @OlegI Check the updated question.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Kindly see the updated question.

Comment: Did you put breakpoints into the code and see it actually runs it several times? And third time: did you check what requests are sent. That’s the biggest thing. First check what requests are made.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen look, i submitted a form on button click suppose it filled a view model CustomerOrderVM and the same function runs 4 times with same VM and its data. YES I HAVE PUT A BREAKPOINT AND CHECKED IT. 
And the issue you are asking, as a result of it suppose i made an order once and i get notified about 4 orders and the same thing happen to DB i mean it lists 4 separate entries of my single order. Thats not what it supposed to do.

Comment: So you didn’t. Please do check the requests. It doesn’t matter if you press a button once. If the code runs multiple requests then fix *that* code. You can’t fix code that’s not broken and assume it fixes the code that is broken. Open the developer tools in the browser. Look at the requests. Determine what’s going on there *first*, don’t assume that the server most likely just responding correctly to requests is the problem here, or threads. Start from the origin and work forward.

Comment: The problem is not about multithreading. The problem is that by one form submission you are getting 4 entries in your database. Am I right @AnasAvais?

Comment: @OlegI yes primarily thats an issue but going through the whoe scenario i found 4 threads running.

Comment: So there’s nothing wrong with having four results and the server side code is just fine. No problem with threads or anything, you can now focus on the actual problem which is why the client side is sending several requests. Is this the exact and whole client side code and there is no other code running, changing how buttons work etc?

Comment: Yeah thanks for the guidance i just quickly moved my focused to threads and secondly i have attached an image to the question showing the calls from browser.. kindly can you indicate anything on that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error and resolved it. I mistakenly mentioned Jquery links (references) on parent and child cshmtl(layout) pages, which was triggering that event multiple time.

Thanks to all who guide me through in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Test(...) method is called for 'Email', 'City', 'Contact' and 'FullName' each. having 4 threads and 4 property if-s is likely not coincidental.